# VBA Macro jumps to another?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any reason why this piece of code

```
Private Sub CT_Company_Loss_Change()

With Application
    .Calculation = xlManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim stSQL As String, rst As ADODB.Recordset, k As Integer, vaData As Variant
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ConnectionString As String, sCompany As String
ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source=se-sqlct-0100;Initial catalog=AirCT2Loss;Integrated Security = SSPI;"
Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

With CY_Program1
        .Clear
        .AddItem "Select Program"
        .ListIndex = 0
End With
```

Gets to the last line and then jumps to this macro:

```
Private Sub CY_Program1_Change()

With Application
    .Calculation = xlManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim stSQL As String, rst As ADODB.Recordset, k As Integer, vaData As Variant
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ConnectionString As String, sCompany As String, sProgram As String
ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source=se-sqlct-0100;Initial catalog=AirCT2Loss;Integrated Security = SSPI;"
Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
```

I have never seen this before and I'm not even using the call feature, so what is making it do it as its bugging my spreadsheet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us some more details? Why do you think it's jumping to that macro?

Comment: CY_Program1_Change() will fire any time there is a change to that listbox (or whatever it is)...my guess is that it's a control.

Comment: I can't see any End Sub in your code,  is this a typo?

Comment: No typo just showing where the code jumps from.

Comment: PowerUser - I have no idea this was working fine until I tried to clear the combobox values before firing the macro.

Comment: Welcome to the world of [events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.htm).

Comment: to avoid this you need to add a private variable in your userform sheet that does what enableevents would do, because in a userform it won't work. Lets say call it "Events" and set it to false at the begin of `CT_Company_Loss_Change`, and at the first line of `CY_Program1_Change`, you need to add : `if events then`. And later at the end of the first sub reset it to `true` to allow events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @sous2817 points out, both `CT_Company_Loss_Change()` and `CY_Program1_Change()` are event handlers, meaning Excel runs them when certain actions take place.  I agree with @sous2817's guess that both "CT_Company_Loss" and "CY_Program1" are controls and that specifically, "CY_Program1" is a listbox (this is evident from how your code interacts with it).

The following line of code causes a "change" to the "CY_Program1" listbox:

```
With CY_Program1
    .Clear
    .AddItem "Select Program"
    .ListIndex = 0
End With
```

So after the function finishes, the very next thing Excel does is trigger the "change" event handler for the "CY_Program1" listbox: `CY_Program1_Change()`

---

**UPDATE**

If you want the `CY_Program1_Change()` event handler to ignore it when you "clear out" the listbox, try adding this at the beginning of the `CY_Program1_Change()` function:

```
If CY_Program1.ListCount = 1 And CY_Program1.List(0) = "Select Program" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Basically, if the CY_Program1 listbox was just "cleared out", it exits without running the rest of the event handler code.

Comment: Thanks Blackhawk that explaination makes sense, so becuase CY_Program1 is driven by CT_Company_Loss is there a way to clear out CY_Prorgam1 each time the user selects a new value from CT_Company_Loss? Or am I over doing it?

Comment: Are the dropdowns sitting out in a worksheet or are they on userforms?

Comment: you wont always have this work-around working for every situation, see my example

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier Disabling events is a much more elegant solution! Carlos, give Patrick's code a try when you get the chance - basically you tell Excel not to trigger events for a short period of time while you "clear out" your listbox, then you turn events back on.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you enable events or disable them in userforms (userform sheet code):

(for a worsheet you can apply same method but in worsksheet code)

```
Option Explicit
Dim Events As Boolean

Private Sub CT_Company_Loss_Change()
With Application
    .Calculation = xlManual 'works only for the exel worksheet, not the userform
    .EnableEvents = False 'works only for the exel worksheet, not the userform
    .ScreenUpdating = False 
End With

Events = False

'much more code here (....)

With CY_Program1
    .Clear
    .AddItem "Select Program"
    .ListIndex = 0
End With

events = True

With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = true
    .ScreenUpdating = true
End With

End sub
```

and in the same userform sheet code :

```
Private Sub CY_Program1_Change()
if events then  'so, if CY_Program1_Change is called/triggered, then if events is false it won't allow the code to run
   'more code (...)
end if
end sub
```